# how to move a sprite like a bouncing ball in andengine using box2d

Tags: android, android-emulator

Hi am doing one app here i need to move sprite like bouncing ball with some force. using box2d how to apply force and velocity and how to move sprite like ball,i did nt get any idea. please any one suggest me...

```
        MainActivity.class: 

      public class MainActivity extends SimpleBaseGameActivity{

            private Camera mCamera;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mBitmapTextureAtlas;
    private ITextureRegion mFaceTextureRegion;

    private BitmapTextureAtlas mOnScreenControlTexture;
    private ITextureRegion mOnScreenControlBaseTextureRegion;
    private ITextureRegion mOnScreenControlKnobTextureRegion;



    @Override
    public EngineOptions onCreateEngineOptions() {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Also try tapping this AnalogOnScreenControl!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);

        return new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE_FIXED, new RatioResolutionPolicy(CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT), this.mCamera);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreateResources() {
        BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.setAssetBasePath("gfx/");

        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas = new BitmapTextureAtlas(this.getTextureManager(), 32, 32, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
        this.mFaceTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory.createFromAsset(this.mBitmapTextureAtlas, this, "face_box.png", 0, 0);
        this.mBitmapTextureAtlas.load();


    }

    @Override
    public Scene onCreateScene() {
        this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());

        final Scene scene = new Scene();
        scene.setBackground(new Background(0.09804f, 0.6274f, 0.8784f));

        final float centerX = (CAMERA_WIDTH - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getWidth()) / 2;
        final float centerY = (CAMERA_HEIGHT - this.mFaceTextureRegion.getHeight()) / 2;
        final Sprite face = new Sprite(centerX, centerY, this.mFaceTextureRegion, this.getVertexBufferObjectManager());
        final PhysicsHandler physicsHandler = new PhysicsHandler(face);
        face.registerUpdateHandler(physicsHandler);

        scene.attachChild(face);



        return scene;
    }


  }
```